# Is AutoLayout useful to deal with the fragmentation of screen size in iOS? Why is there no equivalent tool in Android?

Tags: android, ios, android-layout, user-interface, android-fragments

I am quite new to AutoLayout in iOS. I have read the paper of it and watched two videos in WWDC. I understand that it is quite efficient in dealing with the relations between UI widgets. However, I still don't quite understand how it is better than the traditional springs and structs. As is stated in the [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html)!:

> If you didn’t use Auto Layout, now may be the perfect time to start, especially if you need to support > more than one version of an app. If you use manual or programmatic layout techniques, you're          > responsible for ensuring that the layout adjusts appropriately when text size changes.

**Is there any example which compares the implementation of layouts using strings/struts and AutoLayout?**

Moreover, **is there any comparison between relative layout in Android and AutoLayout?** Both of them deal with the layout problem in a relative way. **What is the main difference between them?**

On the other hand, **would it be useful to adopt AutoLayout in Android to solve the fragmentation problem?** I know that Google has its own set of solutions to deal with fragmentation, for example, use dp instead of px, use RelativeLayout. However, programmers still need to have different XMLs for the layout. **Would AutoLayout be useful in reducing the amount of XML files?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your question is quite broad, and I sort of agree with the 2 close votes, but I can give you some perspective on Autolayout in iOS.

I began writing apps for iPhone when the iPad didn't exist and iPhone OS 3 was the latest and greatest. Yes, it's been a while! ;-)

At that time, Interface Builder was a separate tool from Xcode and Storyboards didn't exist. Springs and struts and manual frame manipulation was the name of the game. I got to know this system and liked it. Especially since the 3.5" screen was the only one around (and then the iPad came), it made UI design and implementation pretty easy.

When Autolayout was introduced, I didn't care for it very much. Initially, I don't think it was very solid or robust, designing constraints in Xcode's (now-integrated) Interface Builder was difficult and often counter-intuitive, and the whole process was much more difficult than my old one.

Skip forward a year or so and I revisited the topic. Now, Xcode was able to generate constraints in Interface Builder pretty reliably and quickly. The only 2 screen sizes were 3.5" Retina, 4.0" Retina and iPad (both of which had the same number of **points**, so screen design was essentially identical), so screen design was still fairly straightforward.

Then came the iPhone 6/6 Plus. And Size Classes. Size Classes weren't implemented automatically, so you'd have to convert all of your old Storyboards, which of course makes sense, but also seemed too painful to me in existing apps. In addition to that, I found it was pretty easy to screw things up accidentally with Size Classes (wait, is that constraint installed in all Sizes or just this one?). Plus, font sizes in particular became a bad issue for me. Back to the drawing board, so to speak.

Here's what I've begun doing recently. This has been greatly effective and I believe takes roughly the same initial effort, but subsequent changes/tweaking of the UI go incredibly quickly.

1. I got rid of all Storyboards and Xibs. Yup. Every. Single. One. I read [this article](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/why-i-dont-use-interface-builder) a while ago. And I hated it. I mean, it really made me mad. I thought, "this guy is SO stupid! Interface Builder really speeds up my development cycle! He must just be doing it wrong!" Then I started noticing that any tweak to my 50+ screen Storyboards took 2-3 minutes to compile just to test, which began bugging me. I thought about breaking the single Storyboard into multiples, which *did* speed things up, but the screen size fragmentation was still making UI design and implementation harder than necessary, so I dumped all of my Storyboards (slowly, of course, and while methodically following the rest of these steps).
2. I learned to love writing an `NSLayoutConstraint` in code. I mean, not just "not hate" it, but to "love" it! Once you begin doing a ton of them, a certain pattern is easy to develop and they almost end up writing themselves. Plus, with care, it's pretty easy to copy and paste one control's constraints and tweak it for all of the rest of the buttons you're laying out on a screen, for example.
3. With everything now set up in code (which, by the way, makes pushing a new `UIViewController` super easy; now, no matter the platform or screen size, it's always, **ALWAYS** as simple as `[[ViewController alloc] init]` and it takes care of the rest!), I figured out a way that works for me to divide up the UI layout process into a few discrete pieces.

My basic `UIViewController` subclass now starts off life looking like this:

```
@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - View Lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupUserInterface];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - UI Setup
- (void)setupUserInterface {
    [self createConstants];
    [self createControls];
    [self setupControls];
    [self layoutControls];
    // Optional
    [self setupNavigationBar];
}
- (void)createConstants {

}
- (void)createControls {

}
- (void)setupControls {

}
- (void)layoutControls {

}

#pragma mark - 
#pragma mark - Optional UI Setup
- (void)setupNavigationBar {

}
@end
```

Then, it's a pretty easy, straightforward process of defining what controls are going to go on the UI, how they need to look, and what "constants" are needed to accomplish that. For instance, let's say I've got a form to lay out and there are several `UITextFields`, each with an associated `UILabel`. I might have the following properties (among others):

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGFloat  labelFontSize;
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGFloat  textFieldFontSize;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIFont  *labelFont;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIFont  *textFieldFontSize;
```

Later, in `-createConstants`, I can determine the font size values based on the screen that's on the device running the app, and can then instantiate an appropriate font using that value. In this way, I have a single place where I go to change values, such as margins, inter-control spacing, font size, text field height, etc. Then, making a change is as simple as changing a number, and re-compiling to test my new UI takes mere seconds (usually <10 seconds) rather than minutes.

This solution has given me both greater speed (due to both decreased compile time as well as decreased time to make the actual change) and greater control (I find it easier to see immediately exact pixel precision in code, rather than having to click a control, click in the Inspector and see that Xcode assigned an arbitrary value, or my view was initially 4 points off, or something like that). Also, this is better than traditional springs and struts because it makes it super easy to lay out elements **in relation** to one another, without having to worry about exact frame dimensions on any platform/screen, much less all of them.

For instance:

1. Say I have a fairly simple screen with a single header label and 5 buttons.
2. I want all of them stacked in a vertical column.
3. I want the label to take up as much space as it needs.
4. I want the buttons to take up the remaining space.
5. I want the buttons to all be the same height.

With springs and structs, you have to do a ton of math to get this done across all platforms/screens. Yes, you can write a simple method that does what you need, but it's even easier with Autolayout.

Here's how I'd do it (remember, this is a completely code-centric approach):

```
- (void)layoutControls {
    [self.view addSubview:label];
    [self.view addSubview:button1];
    [self.view addSubview:button2];
    [self.view addSubview:button3];
    [self.view addSubview:button4];
    [self.view addSubview:button5];

    // Each of the 6 controls gets laid out horizontally with essentially
    // an identical version of this (where margin is a "constant" I've defined):
    [self.view addConstraints:
        [NSLayoutConstraints 
            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(margin)-[label]-(margin)-|"
                     options:0
                     metrics:@{@"margin": @(self.margin)}
                       views:@{@"label": self.label}
        ]
    ];

    // Once all are laid out horizontally, here's how to do the vertical layout
    [self.view addConstraints:
        [NSLayoutConstraints
            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(margin)-[label]-[button1]-[button2(==button1)]-[button3(==button1)]-[button4(==button1)]-[button5(==button1)]-(margin)-|"
                                options:0
                                metrics:@{@"margin": @(self.margin)}
                                  views:@{@"label": self.label,
                                          @"button1": self.button1,
                                          @"button2": self.button2,
                                          @"button3": self.button3, 
                                          @"button4": self.button4, 
                                          @"button5": self.button5}
        ]
    ];

}
```

And that's it. The system will now calculate all of the exact math for you, and it "just works"! That's a lot easier to me than figuring out manual frames and whatnot. Plus, if you decide to add or remove a button later, that's easy to "fix" with autolayout.

With regard to the second part of your question (Android layout), I'm hopeful to find a way to implement a similar methodology as I'm beginning to learn to write apps on Android.

Comment: I agree with you except I haven't yet gotten into Autolayout in code. I invite you to the following thread: https://www.quora.com/How-many-iOS-developers-dont-use-NIBs-Storyboards-and-Constraints